# Fullscreen Video stutters on second monitor laptop

Tags: laptop, video, display

Fullscreen video on my new 1080p monitor is choppy when it comes from my laptop. The same video plays when not full screen. This goes for all video(Flash/MKV, etc), regardless of video resolution.

I have an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4200 Series card in my Thinkpad Edge, Turion X2 2GHz. The computer plays 1080p fine.

Things I've tried:

- Updating Drivers
- Switching cables
- Turning Hardware Acceleration
- Changing video players process priority
- Rebooting
- Turning of laptop screen
- Turning off unused processes

Nothing Works. What is the likelyhood that my laptop cannot power a 1920x1280 display?

Answer (score 0):

I have read that a similar issue like this for fullscreen video in VLC can be resolved by **right clicking VLC.exe** and then goto **properties** and look under the **compatibility tab** and **check the box labeled: "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings"**